# Clevo N150RD BSOD driver power state failure

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, bsod, nvidia-geforce, nvidia-graphics-card

as the title says, I'm getting a BSOD with driver power state failure on Windows 10 64 bit. In details, I'm getting the error while I use After Effects oh Agisoft Photoscan with high settings. Checking the dump file on OSR Online seems that the problem is the graphic card, while using Blue Screen View it says that the process is ntoskrnl.exe but I don't know to what it refers to. Testing the GPU with Unigine I have no error nor BSOD, also using CPU stress software I have no problem. It seems related to just the aformentioned programs. I tried to update the gpu drivers with the latest downloadable from Nvidia, but nothing changes so I reinstalled the ones from the manufacter. Here's my configuration:

- Brand and model: Clevo N150RD
- Intel i7 6700 HQ
- Ram 16gb ddr3
- Nvidia GTX 960
- SSD 120gb and HDD 1Tb
- Intel AC8260 wifi
- Windows 10 64 bit

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: You failed to mention versions of your drivers

Comment: Blue Screen View is **CRAP**. Share the dmp files from **C:\Windows\Minidump**

Comment: Here is the minidump: http://pastebin.com/XkmMPm27

Comment: I need the DMP file, no text

Comment: @magicandre1981 sorry, here are the last dumps: 
https://mega.nz/#!OoAnAa5b!4kGPo9NpChm1qE61OqZuD9_qlSgQGBqNE-L1rY9Ip84

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, 1 of the 3 dumps shows an fatal Hwardware error of your Intel i7 HQ

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR (124)
A fatal hardware error has occurred. Parameter 1 identifies the type of error
source that reported the error. Parameter 2 holds the address of the
WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure that describes the error conditon.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, Machine Check Exception
Arg2: ffffe00147ab4028, Address of the WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure.
Arg3: 00000000ba000000, High order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.
Arg4: 0000000011000402, Low order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.

Debugging Details:
------------------

*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for igdkmd64.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for igdkmd64.sys

DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10586.122.amd64fre.th2_release_inmarket.160222-1549

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  Notebook                        

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  N15_17RD

SYSTEM_SKU:  Not Applicable                  

SYSTEM_VERSION:  Not Applicable                  

BIOS_VENDOR:  American Megatrends Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  1.05.07

BIOS_DATE:  10/23/2015

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  Notebook                        

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  N15_17RD

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  Not Applicable                  

DUMP_TYPE:  2

STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 hal!HalBugCheckSystem
02 nt!WheaReportHwError
03 hal!HalpMcaReportError
04 hal!HalpMceHandlerCore
05 hal!HalpMceHandler
06 hal!HalpMceHandlerWithRendezvous
07 hal!HalHandleMcheck
08 nt!KxMcheckAbort
09 nt!KiMcheckAbort
0a igdkmd64

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x124_GenuineIntel_PROCESSOR_MAE

BUCKET_ID:  0x124_GenuineIntel_PROCESSOR_MAE

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0x124_GenuineIntel_PROCESSOR_MAE

BUILDLAB_STR:  th2_release_inmarket

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.10586.122.amd64fre.th2_release_inmarket.160222-1549

2: kd> !errrec ffffe00147ab4028
===============================================================================
Common Platform Error Record @ ffffe00147ab4028
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Record Id     : 01d175ee193d98b3
Severity      : Fatal (1)
Length        : 928
Creator       : Microsoft
Notify Type   : Machine Check Exception
Timestamp     : 3/4/2016 16:04:45 (UTC)
Flags         : 0x00000000

===============================================================================
Section 0     : Processor Generic
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffe00147ab40a8
Section       @ ffffe00147ab4180
Offset        : 344
Length        : 192
Flags         : 0x00000001 Primary
Severity      : Fatal

Proc. Type    : x86/x64
Instr. Set    : x64
Error Type    : Micro-Architectural Error
Flags         : 0x00
CPU Version   : 0x00000000000506e3
Processor ID  : 0x0000000000000002

===============================================================================
Section 1     : x86/x64 Processor Specific
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffe00147ab40f0
Section       @ ffffe00147ab4240
Offset        : 536
Length        : 128
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Local APIC Id : 0x0000000000000002
CPU Id        : e3 06 05 00 00 08 10 02 - bf fb fa 7f ff fb eb bf
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Proc. Info 0  @ ffffe00147ab4240

===============================================================================
Section 2     : x86/x64 MCA
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffe00147ab4138
Section       @ ffffe00147ab42c0
Offset        : 664
Length        : 264
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Error         : Internal unclassified (Proc 2 Bank 4)
  Status      : 0xba00000011000402

2: kd> !sysinfo cpuinfo
[CPU Information]
~MHz = REG_DWORD 2592
Component Information = REG_BINARY 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Configuration Data = REG_FULL_RESOURCE_DESCRIPTOR ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Identifier = REG_SZ Intel64 Family 6 Model 94 Stepping 3
ProcessorNameString = REG_SZ Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
Update Status = REG_DWORD 2
VendorIdentifier = REG_SZ GenuineIntel
MSR8B = REG_QWORD 4900000000
2: kd> !sysinfo machineid
Machine ID Information [From Smbios 3.0, DMIVersion 0, Size=3017]
BiosMajorRelease = 5
BiosMinorRelease = 11
BiosVendor = American Megatrends Inc.
BiosVersion = 1.05.07
BiosReleaseDate = 10/23/2015
SystemManufacturer = Notebook                        
SystemProductName = N15_17RD
SystemFamily = Not Applicable                  
SystemVersion = Not Applicable                  
SystemSKU = Not Applicable                  
BaseBoardManufacturer = Notebook                        
BaseBoardProduct = N15_17RD
BaseBoardVersion = Not Applicable                  
2: kd> !sysinfo cpuinfo
[CPU Information]
~MHz = REG_DWORD 2592
Component Information = REG_BINARY 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Configuration Data = REG_FULL_RESOURCE_DESCRIPTOR ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Identifier = REG_SZ Intel64 Family 6 Model 94 Stepping 3
ProcessorNameString = REG_SZ Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
Update Status = REG_DWORD 2
VendorIdentifier = REG_SZ GenuineIntel
MSR8B = REG_QWORD 4900000000
2: kd> !sysinfo cpuspeed
CPUID:        "Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz"
MaxSpeed:     2600
CurrentSpeed: 2592
```

But I have no idea what this `Internal unclassified` error is. Look for a BIOS/UEFI update for your laptop. The Intel HD driver igdkmd64.sys, is from 2015, so also try the [latest 4300 driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25489/Intel-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-10-15-40-4th-Gen-).

The nvlddmkm.sys is shown as cause for the 2 `DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)` crashes.

```
0: kd> !podev ffffe000ae815060
Device object is for:
  DriverObject ae80a8a0
Current Irp 00000000 RefCount 0 Type 00000023 AttachedDev ffffe000ae814480 DevFlags 00001040
Device queue is not busy.
Device Object Extension: ffffe000ae8157b0:
PowerFlags: 00000040 =>SystemState=0 DeviceState=4
Dope: 00000000:
0: kd> !devstack ffffe000ae814480
  !DevObj           !DrvObj            !DevExt           ObjectName
  ffffe000b0358120  \Driver\nvlddmkm   ffffe000b0358270  InfoMask field not found for _OBJECT_HEADER at ffffe000b03580f0

> ffffe000ae814480  \Driver\ACPI       ffffe000ada1a8d0  InfoMask field not found for _OBJECT_HEADER at ffffe000ae814450

  ffffe000ae815060  \Driver\pci        ffffe000ae8151b0  Cannot read info offset from nt!ObpInfoMaskToOffset

!DevNode ffffe000ae815d30 :
  DeviceInst is "PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_139B&SUBSYS_01521558&REV_A2\4&bed9ab3&0&0008"
  ServiceName is "nvlddmkm"
0: kd> lmvm nvlddmkm

    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\nvlddmkm.sys
    Image name: nvlddmkm.sys
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Sat Nov 14 06:44:20 2015 (5646CA34)
```

The nVIDIA driver is from Nov 2015, so try the [driver 362.00 WHQL](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/99204/en-us).

Comment: Hi! I've tried the latest Nvidia driver but nothing changes. I've contacted the support of my laptop, and they said that there is a bios update for my model, so monday I'll proceed with the update and let you know. In your opinion, could the bios update really resolve the problem?

Comment: it can fix the 0x124 issue which may also fix the GPU related crashes.

Comment: I've update the bios and seems that there are no more bsod. Thanks a lot!